# Best pattern for returning one of set of types of data

Tags: c++, regex, parameter-passing

I have  method that accepts a string and uses regex methods to determine if that string represents a float, int or string.

What is the best pattern to return the resultant float, int or string?

So my basic method prototype is:

```
void interpretString(const std::string &s);
```

What is the best way to get back the resultant float, int or string?
At present I extended my method as follows:

```
enum dataType { None, String, Float, Int };
dataType interpretString(const std::string &s,
                         string &s,
                         float &f,
                         int &i);
```

where the data is returned in the corresponding s, f or i variables. This seems unsatisfactory, as I am passing around data that will never get used (e.g. if the input string is a float, the string and integer return values will be unused)

Is there a better way?

Comment: Use `boost::variant` or define your own `union`.

Comment: Something like boost any might be a good return type. However, if you limit it to floating point, integer or string, you might use a union with type information (int, float string).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method using function objects:

```
struct Evaluation_Assignment
{
  virtual void assign(const std::string& s) = 0;
  virtual void assign(int i) = 0;
  virtual void assign(double d) = 0;
};

void Interpret_String(const std::string string_to_process,
                      Evaluation_Assignment& processor)
{
  if (interpretation_was_string)
  {
     processor.assign(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is incomplete, needs to be filled in by the OP.  As for performance, that was not a criteria.  This version is nice because you can pass different instances for different assignments.  It is presented as an alternative.